# Coax web page into showing more data?

Tags: html, jsoup

This is a weird question and I don't even know if I am asking it correctly, but I am writing a Java program using jsoup to extract the names of popular manga from this website: http://www.mangareader.net/popular. Each page only shows 30 mangas and there are 3950 mangas on this website, so I was wondering if it is possible to edit the webpage so that each page would show more comics (so that I wouldn't have to keep loading new pages over and over again)? I also noticed something about the URL of the webpage: if you were to go to http://www.mangareader.net/popular/1, it will show comics 2 - 31, and if you go to http://www.mangareader.net/popular/2, it will show comics 3 - 32 . You can keep changing the URL this way to show a different range of comics. Maybe that's something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyhow you have to crawl all the pages one by one. Even if there exists an URL to increase the no of results per page, that URL is only known to the web developer who created this website.

Answer (score 0):

its using pagination. you have the right idea, just keep cycling through the pages until you get a page with no results then you know you hit the end.

Comment: The page with no results was the 3950th page, so I knew there were 3950 comics, but I want to be able to view more of them on one page because it will only show 30 comics at the most...if that makes sense?

Comment: it makes sense, but unless the website allows you to choose the number of results per page (for example, by passing it as a parameter just like the current page), you cant do anything.